# Spark Joins with None Values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, right-join

I am trying to perform a join in Spark knowing that one of my keys on the left does not have a corresponding value in the other RDD.

The documentation says it should perform the join with None as an option if no key is found, but I keep getting a type mismatch error.

Any insight here?

Comment: It's easier to help with the piece of code you have trouble with, or at least a small example demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take these two RDDs:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Array(("test","foo"),("test2", "foo2")))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Array(("test","foo3"),("test3", "foo4")))
```

When you join them, you have a couple of options. What you do depends on what you want. Do you want an RDD only with the common keys?

```
val leftJoined = rdd1.join(rdd2)
leftJoined.collect
res1: Array[(String, (String, String))] = Array((test,(foo,foo3)))
```

If you want keys missing from `rdd2` to be filled in with `None`, use `leftOuterJoin`:

```
val leftOuter = rdd.leftOuterJoin(rdd2)
leftOuter.collect
res2: Array[(String, (String, Option[String]))] = Array((test2,(foo2,None)), (test,(foo,Some(foo3))))
```

If you want keys missing from either side to be filled in with `None`, use `fullOuterJoin`:

```
val fullOuter =  rdd1.fullOuterJoin(rdd2)
fullOuter.collect
res3: Array[(String, (Option[String], Option[String]))] = Array((test2,(Some(foo2),None)), (test3,(None,Some(foo4))), (test,(Some(foo),Some(fo3))))
```